# How can I access the url attribute in a user's groups in the Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am listing the `memberof` information of the user.

How can I access the url property value in the attribute properties of each member within the memberof group?

```
user
--Memberof1
----Memberof1 group properties attribute url:
----Memberof1 group properties attribute name:
----Memberof1 group properties attribute grouptype:
----Memberof1 group properties attribute description:
--Memberof2
----Memberof2 group properties attribute url:
----Memberof2 group properties attribute name:
----Memberof2 group properties attribute grouptype:
----Memberof2 group properties attribute description:
--Memberof3
----Memberof3 group properties attribute url:
----Memberof3 group properties attribute name:
----Memberof3 group properties attribute grouptype:
----Memberof3 group properties attribute description:
```

My code:

```
public static ActiveDirectoryUser SearchActiveDirectoryUserDetail(string samAccount)
{
    var user = new ActiveDirectoryUser { SamId = samAccount };

    var ldapPath = "LDAP://" + Environment.UserDomainName;
    var searchFilter =
                "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)" +
                $"(sAMAccountName={samAccount}))";

    string[] searchProperties =
            {
                "samaccountname",
                "givenName",
                "sn",
                "telephoneNumber",
                "mail",
                "title",
                "memberOf"
            };

    try
    {
        using (var parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath))
        using (var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(parentEntry, searchFilter, searchProperties))
        using (var searchResultCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searchResultCollection)
            {
                if (searchResultCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    var entry = new DirectoryEntry(searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Path);

                    user.SamId = entry.Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null
                                ? entry.Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString()
                                : string.Empty;

                    user.NameFirst = entry.Properties["givenName"].Value != null
                                ? entry.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString()
                                : string.Empty;

                    user.NameLast = entry.Properties["sn"].Value != null
                                ? entry.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString()
                                : string.Empty;

                    user.OfficePhone = entry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value != null
                                ? entry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString()
                                : string.Empty;

                    user.EmailAddress = entry.Properties["mail"].Value != null
                                ? entry.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString()
                                : string.Empty;

                    user.JobTitle = entry.Properties["title"].Value != null
                                ? entry.Properties["title"].Value.ToString()
                                : string.Empty;

                    if (entry.Properties["memberOf"] != null)
                        user.MemberOf = entry.Properties["memberOf"];

                    for (var i = 0; i < user.MemberOf.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        var startIndex =
                                    user.MemberOf[i].ToString().IndexOf("CN=", 0, StringComparison.Ordinal) + 3;
                        var endIndex = user.MemberOf[i].ToString().IndexOf(",", startIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal);

                        user.MemberOf[i] = user.MemberOf[i].ToString()
                                               .Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

                        /* memberof groups properties attribute */
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //
    }

    return user;
}

public class ActiveDirectoryUser
{
    public string SamId { get; set; }
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    public string NameLast { get; set; }
    public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get;set; }
    public PropertyValueCollection MemberOf { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Are you looking for the [`wWWHomePage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-wwwhomepage) attribute, which is a single-value attribute? Or the [`url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-url) attribute, which is multi-value?

Comment: You're also really slowing down your code by calling `GetDirectoryEntry()` to read the attributes. See here for why: https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html#dont-use-getdirectoryentry

Comment: I will use the link you provided to improve my code execution performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MemberOf is a collection of group DN like "CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com". you have to do a secondary search to get group object based on DN, and then get its attributes.
try this :

modify for/loop  :

```
for (var i = 0; i < user.MemberOf.Count; ++i)
    {
        var startIndex =
                    user.MemberOf[i].ToString().IndexOf("CN=", 0, StringComparison.Ordinal) + 3;
        var endIndex = user.MemberOf[i].ToString().IndexOf(",", startIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal);

        user.MemberOf[i] = user.MemberOf[i].ToString()
                               .Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

        /* memberof groups properties attribute */
        DirectoryEntry mof = GetGroupByDN(user.MemberOf[i]);
        string mName = mof.name;
        string mUrl = mof.url;  //note : I dont know if .url attribute exist....)
    
    }
```

and add this function :

```
private static DirectoryEntry GetGroupByDN(string sDN)
{
    string adPath = "LDAP://" + Environment.UserDomainName;
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(adPath + "/" + sDN);
    DirectoryEntry deManager = null;

    using (DirectorySearcher Search = new DirectorySearcher())
    {
        Search.SearchRoot = de;
        Search.Filter = "(&(distinguishedName=" + sDN + "))";
        //Search.Filter = "(objectClass = group)";
        Search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base;
        SearchResult Result = Search.FindOne();

        if (null != Result)
            deManager = Result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    }
    return deManager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did what I wanted to do with the code below.
Thank you to everyone who commented.

```
public static void MemberOfDetails(string username, ListBox lb)
        {
            var ldapPath = "LDAP://" + Environment.UserDomainName;

            var rootDe = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath);
            var dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootDe);
            dSearcher.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + username + ")(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))";
            var sResult = dSearcher.FindOne();

            if (sResult != null)
            {
                foreach (var grp in sResult.Properties["memberOf"])
                {
                    var sGrpName = Convert.ToString(grp).Remove(0, 3).Split(',')[0];
                    try
                    {
                        var gSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootDe);
                        gSearcher.Filter = "sAMAccountName=" + sGrpName;
                        var gResult = gSearcher.FindOne();
                        var fullPathName = gResult?.Properties["url"][0].ToString();

                        if (fullPathName != null)
                        {                           
                            lb.Items.Add(fullPathName);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).